# Is there a way to enable django DEBUG mode using nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I deployed my project on served with nginx and gunicorn. When I am trying to access a particular endpoint there is an error: "500 Internal Server Error", that is bad, so I have decided to enable django debug mode, but nothing has changed. Instead of informative traceback, I get an uninformative http status code, so how can I change it?

Comment: Did you restart gunicorn?

Comment: If you know an another way to see traceback, please, let me know.

Comment: Enable debug in settings.py then restart the gunicorn service

Comment: I use docker-compose. After I enabled django debug mode, I have restarted all the containers.